# Can I tell Photos to please stop auto-rotating my perfectly fine pictures?

Tags: macos, photos, high-sierra

Often, when I open the crop panel for a photo that I've just recently imported, Photos helpfully rotates it all wrong for me.

[image: Photo rotate by almost 4° on a whim of Photos.]

I think that it tried to make the shadows straight. This is Clippy-level infuriating and essentially never useful. Can I stop Photos from doing that?

Comment: I totally hear you. It's super annoying and apparently nobody knows how to stop photos.app from doing it. :(